# Replacing 1 usage of activerecord_any_of with vanilla rails 5+ or() method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I inherited a Ruby on Rails app that has to be upgraded to the latest version of Rails (7). The app uses the activerecord_any_of gem (not compatible with Rails >= 6) and it does that in only 1 place, so I'm wondering if I can just replace that one line where it's used with different syntax. Mind you I've never done any Ruby programming but have done other languages, so I'm just hacking my way here (feel free to tell me I'm way off).

There's one line where any_of is used and it looks like this:
`results = base_relation.where.any_of(*document_conditions)`

where `document_conditions` is a list of conditions generated dynamically inside of a loop, and they're of the format `{key1: value, key2: value}`

Is there any way to replace that line with something that uses the where().or() construct? Given that the list is dynamic, it would have to be done in a dynamic way so I'm wondering if that can be done with something like a reduce() construct to chain the or() over the array of conditions?

Thanks if you've read this :)

Comment: You could eventually replace what's in `document_conditions` for a series of chained `or`s. Can you add the value of `document_conditions` to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
results = document_conditions.inject(base_relation) do |relation, (key, value)|
  relation.or(base_relation.where(key => value))
end
```

Comment: To avoid the dreaded structural compatibility error maybe `relation.or(base_relation.where(key => value))`

Comment: Thank you both for the quick responses. After trying a bit I figured I'm gonna need a bit more help with this codebase so it's now being dealt with by someone else. I never got to test this, but I've pointed them to this question and hopefully they will try your answer and find it helpful. I'll report back if they try it and it works and mark this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @engineersmnky You are certainly right. I updated my answer to address your comment.